# Android Volley access http response header fields

Tags: java, android, http, android-volley

How can i access HTTP header fields like ETag from a response using Volley ?
With `HttpUrlCoonection` i just do `conn.getHeaderField("ETag")` and that's it.

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can subclass `Request` (or any of its subclasses) and override the `parseNetworkResponse` method:

```
@Override
protected Response<Bitmap> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    Map<String, String> responseHeaders = response.headers;
}
```

Comment: You are right. But volley adds some extra header kay-values. Is there a filter for getting only server headers?

Answer (score 5):

You can extend `Request` class. Then when you implement `parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response)` method you can access header values in `response.headers`. So you can access ETag header like `response.headers.get("ETag")`. What I did was to then add this header value in response object like `response.setETag(etag)` and than I just return it in `Response.success(response, null)`. Response object will then be delivered to `deliverResponse(E response)` where you can send it forward to some listener.