# Get the header value from the android volley

Tags: android, json, header, android-volley

Can someone please guide me that how to get the header value from the url. I have referred to many tutorials but i could not find any tutorial to get the header value from json. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
JsonArrayRequest obreq = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, JsonURL,




                // The third parameter Listener overrides the method onResponse() and passes
                //JSONObject as a parameter
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {



                    // Takes the response from the JSON request
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {



                        pbHeaderProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        try {

                            // Retrieves the string labeled "colorName" and "description" from
                            //the response JSON Object
                            //and converts them into javascript objects

                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {


                                JSONObject jresponse = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                String id = jresponse.getString("id");
                                Id.add(id);

                                String auth = jresponse.getString("DJ_author_name");
                                Author.add(auth);


                                String date = jresponse.getString("date_gmt");

                                SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
                                java.util.Date date4 = null;
                                try {
                                    date4 = form.parse(date);
                                } catch (ParseException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }



                                Date.add(newDateStr);


                                JSONObject title = jresponse.getJSONObject("title");
                                String tit = title.getString("rendered");

                                Title.add(tit);


                                JSONObject img = jresponse.getJSONObject("better_featured_image");
                                String pic = img.getString("source_url");
                                Image.add(pic);

                            }


                            // Adds strings from object to the "data" string
                            linear.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
                            // Adds the data string to the TextView "results"
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }

                        // Try and catch are included to handle any errors due to JSON
                        catch (JSONException e) {
                            // If an error occurs, this prints the error to the log
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },




                // The final parameter overrides the method onErrorResponse() and passes VolleyError
                //as a parameter
                new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    // Handles errors that occur due to Volley
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        pbHeaderProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Toast.makeText(Home.this, "error!!! =)",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        noi.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
                        Log.e("Volley", "Error");
                    }
                }


        );



        obreq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                30000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        // Adds the JSON object request "obreq" to the request queue
        requestQueue.add(obreq);
```

Comment: do u want to parse json in android ?

Comment: you can't get header value in your response so don't try :)

Answer (score 0):

please check djodjos answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36430958/getting-headers-from-a-response-in-volley)

if you mean you want to get the header values of the json that is returned itself, not the headers of the request itself you can use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library it's fast reliable and very easy to use

------- Ok then as djodjos answer

```
 @Override
protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers, PROTOCOL_CHARSET));
        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        jsonResponse.put("headers", new JSONObject(response.headers));
        return Response.success(jsonResponse,
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JSONException je) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
    }    }
```

---

you need to override parseNetworkResponse when you create the new JsonArrayRequest (obreq )
for example

```
 StringRequest request=new StringRequest(GET,"url",listener,errorListener){
        @Override
        protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            String totalPages=responseHeaders.get("X-WP-TotalPages");
            return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
        }
    };
```

Comment: how to get this value inside the main code

Comment: can u link this code with my above code

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass Request (or any of its subclasses) and override the parseNetworkResponse method:

```
 @Override
    protected Response<Bitmap> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response)
{ 

     Map<String, String> responseHeaders = response.headers;
}
```

with reference to this [stackoverflow's link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702178/android-volley-access-http-response-header-fields)

Comment: can u explain it , it asks for an return statement